# Why is flex not working in VS Code or Glitch, but does work in Codepen?

Tags: flexbox

I have a very simple piece of code, and I'm wondering why this (flex) will not work in VS or Glitch, but does in Codepen? How do I make it work in VS and Glitch?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-1">Home</div>
    <div class="box-2">About</div>
    <div class="box-3">Services</div>
    <div class="box-4">Contacts</div>
</div>


*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
```

I tried finding the answer, and using multiple editors.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We'll need more information as to what doesn't work, is there an error, no styles are being applied, etc.? With that being said, sounds like a reference error. Check the browser's developer tools and check the console to see if there is a reference error to your CSS.

Comment: Omg I had a setting wrong. I was upset about this all day, and I guess I just needed someone to tell me to double linked CSS file :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) will let you see where/what styles are being applied.

The snippet below/above works as expected so double check your browsers developer tools console and check to see if maybe your CSS file reference is broken.

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-1">Home</div>
    <div class="box-2">About</div>
    <div class="box-3">Services</div>
    <div class="box-4">Contacts</div>
</div>
```